# Expression for "little people"

Tags: expression, idiomaticity

What is an idiomatic way of expressing "little people", not as in people literally of small stature but people who are in reality important while still being "officially" unimportant?-- most notably seen in the popular quote:

> I want to thank all the little people who made this possible...

Unfortunately, on e.g. [dict.cc, all the translations for "little people" refer to people who are actually small (e.g. *das kleine Volk*)](https://www.dict.cc/?s=little%20people).

Comment: *Heinzelmännchen* are helpful little people. I've heard this word in acknowledgements some times

Comment: Isn't "little people" a bit rude? I imagine a very proud person saying that, in a disregarding way (as if he can't be bothered to list out their names).

Comment: @Numeri: Yes, this term isn't exactly the most flattering one.

Comment: `Fußvolk` means the base [ant] members of an organisation/institution in contrast to the top members/élite.

Comment: @userunknown: Thanks for the heads-up regarding the typo... but, no, I'd never interpret *little people have small feet* to mean "few people have small feet".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally, I’ve never encountered *little people* being used that way in English, but I’m not a native speaker and since there are some similar phrases in German I’ve no doubt it can refer to unknown or invisible helpers instead of midgets, children or dwarves/hobbits.

There is a fixed expression, *der kleine Mann auf der Straße* ‘the little man on the street’, which refers to Joe Sixpack (aka. *Otto Normalverbraucher*) and has no common female counterpart, but a related plural form, *die kleinen Leute* ‘the small/little people’.

Maybe one of the following suggestions fits better:

- *Menschen hinter den Kulissen* or *… dem Vorhang, … der Bühne* ‘people behind the curtains’
- *Leute im Hintergrund* ‘people in the background’
- *viele fleißige Hände* ‘many busy hands’ or, with alliteration, *helfende Hände* ‘helping hands’
- *Helfer ohne Namen / namenlose Helfer* ‘nameless helpers’
- *unbekannte Gesichter* ‘unknown faces’
- *hilfreiche Geister* ‘helpful spirits/ghosts’
- *gute Seele* ‘good soul/spirit’ – usual a single low-level but beloved employee, a mother or father figure
- *unzählige Beteiligte* ‘countless parties involved’
- *wahre Helden* ‘real heroes’
- *(Zahn-)Räder die die Maschine(rie) am Laufen halten* ‘(gear) wheels that keep the machine running’
- *alle, die einen/ihren Beitrag geleistet haben* ‘everyone who contributed’

The following can be rather accusing or derogatory:

- *Mitläufer* ‘tag-along, hanger-on’
- *Kollaborateure* ‘collaborator’
- *Helfer und Helfershelfer* ‘helpers and their helpers’

Comment: I think that `Mitläufer` does not fit the context. And i never heard `Kollaborateure` in a context other than "People who (opportunistically) helped the Nazi forces that at the time ahd occupied the country".

Comment: @Burki I had added the final three terms, below the warning, because I anticipated that some non-native speakers might find them elsewhere and think they fit the theme.